# Posting video on Facebook page from iOS and Android app in background

Tags: android, ios, facebook

I want to post video on Facebook page from iOS and Android app without showing Post dialogue from facebook. Video should be posted in background and display on Facebook page.

Comment: Are you implying skipping user consent? or omitting the visual confirmation step?

Comment: @ArsenyLevin: omitting the visual confirmation steps.